# C++ string.data() function

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to understand this piece of code that overload the operator `>>`. I guess what I don't understand is why not have 
`is.open(fileName);` instead of `is.open(fileName.data());`.
or what is the exact functionality of `fileName.data()`.

```
ifstream& operator>> (ifstream& is, TheMatrix& myMatrix)
{
string fileName;
cout << "Enter a file name -> ";
cin >> fileName;
is.open(fileName.data());
for (int i=0; i< 5; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        is >> myMatrix.M[i][j];
return is;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data

Comment: In this case, `data()` does precisely nothing, because (1) your code does not compile, and (2) because `data()`'s return value is ignored :)

Comment: here I added the whole routine.

Comment: never mind it just returns the address of the file.

Comment: I don't know what *"it just returns the address of the file"* means, but that is not what the `data()` function does. It has nothing to do with files.

Comment: in this case it does. putting a cout exactly after the `is.open(fileName.data());` shows that.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. `is.open(fileName.data()); cout << ?????` -- How could that cout statement possibly tell you what `fileName.data()` returns?

Comment: `cout << fileName.data();` it basically shows the address of file read. create a main program and run it and you see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not have is.open(fileName);

Using a modern implementation of the standard library, you can, and should, do exactly that. (Although you really shouldn't be accepting user input and opening the file in the input operator; it would make much more sense to overload `operator>>()` for the more generic `istream` rather than `ifstream`.)

In old versions of the standard library, `ifstream::open(filename)` took a C-style string (a pointer to a zero-terminated `char` array) as it's argument, and not a C++-style `std::string`. Therefore, to use a C++ string, you needed to convert it to a C string: `filename.c_str()`.

Using `data()` rather than `c_str()` is wrong. It doesn't necessarily give a properly terminated string and, if not, you'll get undefined behaviour if you try to treat it as one.

Comment: reading you're post again, it makes sense completely now. You were right, and I was wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess than **searching** for it on google **before** asking it here would have been better.

> Get string data
>   Returns a pointer to an array of characters with the same content as the string.
>
> Notice that no terminating null character is appended (see member c_str for such a functionality).
>
> The returned array points to an internal location which should not be modified directly in the program. Its contents are guaranteed to remain unchanged only until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object.

Comment: Note that it does include a null terminator since C++11.

Comment: Thanks, I did read this in cplusplus.com, but i don't completely understand what it does in above code. Update: I added the whole routine.

Comment: it just returns the address of file

Answer (score 0):

It returns the full string data including any embedded 0. `filename.c_str()` will return the string only up to any terminating 0.

Btw, the code fragment won't compile because the variables have different case.

Comment: true, thanks. I should be more careful int the future, since I got a lot of negative votes on this. But to be short the `.data()` just returns the address of that file.

Comment: What do you mean it returns "the full string data"?  That makes no sense.  It returns a `char*`.  If the string is const, or is being referenced as const, then it returns a `const char*`, just like `c_str()`.  Only difference is that the pointer that `c_str()` returns is guaranteed to point to a null-terminated string, which may or may not be the actual string data.  On any sane implementation, the string data is null-terminated anyway, and both `data()` and `c_str()` return the exact same address.